# How to calculate sectional curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

I'm some new here, sorry if my question is not correct. I need to calculate the sectional curvature of a Riemannian manifold. I found this formula in several books.

$$K(\sigma,p)=\frac{R(X,Y,Y,X)}{g(X,X)g(Y,Y)-g(X,Y)}$$

My problem is that none of them do the detailed accounts, and it frustrates me because most that I have been able to read have a different notation. I am quite confused, I would like to know if anyone knows any book where I can find some text that makes a summary of the formulas (from defining the metric, **Christoffel symbols**, Riemannian tensor, etc.) and applies them in an example to understand. And if someone would be so kind to do it here, I would be very grateful, it does not matter if it is a simple example such as the sphere or hyperbolic space or a surface of revolution I don't know... I just want to see the technique to be able to understand and apply it.

Comment: This [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry) is a compilation of formulae in Riemannian geometry.

Comment: I suggest doing the sphere in two different ways. One is to use the coordinates of the upper half written as a graph, computing the metric $g$, then the Christoffel symbols, and the curvature tensor. It’s a long messy calculation but worth doing. The second way is to do it using stereographic projection.

Comment: The last term in denominator needs to be squared as well, $g(X,Y)g(X,Y)$, or there is a mismatch in the unit "length squared".

Comment: @Didier I know that there are many formulas, my problem is not to find the formulas but how to use them effectively, since there are several steps, I do not know how to use them well and I get confused. That is why I created the question, to look for explicit examples that help me to better systematize the method of how to calculate the sectional curvature of a variety, I am not looking for complicated examples but simple but where steps are not omitted, to have everything clear.

Comment: @Leeland There is not a unique way to compute sectional curvature and it really depends on the point of view you choose on Riemannian geometry. Some people would prefer computing curvature with Christoffel symbols, some other with Jacobi fields, some others with Lie Group actions, *etc.* If you want some examples (which do not cover all the techniques), just take any good Riemannian geometry book and go to the dedicated section. For instance, *Riemannian Geometry*, Gallot, Hulin & Lafontaine, or Riemannian Geometry, Petersen, or Jack Lee's book.

Comment: @Didier I understand, I'm interested in calculating the sectional curvature by means of the Christoffel symbols. Thanks for the references I hope to find what I'm looking for there.

Comment: [Here](http://www.rdrop.com/~half/math/torus/torus.geodesics.pdf) the Riemann-, Ricci- and scalar curvature of the torus are computed explicitly. Maybe it helps.